Can you have multiple copies of same data in cpu cache
From wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_coherence

Multiple copies of same data can exist in different cache simultaneously and if processors are allowed to update their own copies freely, an inconsistent view of memory can result.

What does this mean?
For example if you have
int myInt;
Does it mean that in a single core L1 cache can have multiple copies of myInt? Thats not possible right? Because tag and index is checked to ensure uniqueness in l1 cache?
or does it mean that each level of cache have unique data, but l1 can have 1 copy of myInt and l2 can have a separate copies of myInt ? If thats the case how does cache coherence work? which copy is more correct? does l1 cache sync with l2 cache and vice versa when dirty write happens?
or perhaps its referring to multi core
where each core can have a separate copy of myInt? in this case, how does cache coherence work in multicore environment?

Usually CPU caches are designed to avoid homonym and synonym problems (see Virtually indexed physically tagged cache Synonym for a discussion).  So each cache has at most one valid copy, but separate caches can have copies. (Like L1d and L2 of the same core, plus shared L3. And if the line is in Shared state, maybe also caches in other cores).  Re: cache coherence, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MESI_protocol and What cache coherence solution do modern x86 CPUs use?

Some designs have one level of cache exclusive of another, so they can't both have a copy of the same data.  Some are inclusive, so for something to be cached in L1d or L2, it must be valid in L3 for example (Intel i7, and Xeon before Skylake)

which copy is more correct? - If multiple valid copies exist, they all hold the same data so they're all equally valid (MESI Shared state).  Coherent caches prevent multiple disagreeing copies of a cache line from ever existing in cache itself.  Semi-related: When to use volatile with multi threading? talks about that some.

The quote is specifically referring to the last of your three possibilities (since it discusses "processors allowed to update their own copies freely").
